# Google static maps don´t load in iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I'm programming a game in Unity and I need to load a static map. The map are correctly displayed in the editor, and in Android devices, but not in iOS devices. It says the url is incorrect... I don´t know what is the solution. Can anybody help me?

I call the map  with this code:

```
url= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+fixLat+","+fixLon+"&zoom="+zoom+"&scale=2&size=640x640&style=feature:all|element:geometry|hue:0x00fff0|lightness:0|gamma:0.21|visibility:on&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape.man_made|element:geometry|color:0x133f42|visibility:on&style=feature:landscape.natural|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|hue:0x00ffd2|saturation:35|lightness:0|gamma:0.5&style=feature:poi|element:geometry.fill|lightness:0|gamma:0.6|visibility:on&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|visibility:on|saturation:0|color:0x2e9470&style=feature:road|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|color:0x05111a&style=feature:road|element:geometry.stroke|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|element:geometry|visibility:off"+key;
```

This is the full code to call the url:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Gpsconnect : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Transform user;                  
public bool simGPS = true;                          
public float userSpeed = 5.0f;                  
public bool realSpeed = false;                  
public float fixLat = 42.3627f;     
public float fixLon = -71.05686f;           
public float altitude;          
public float heading;           
public float accuracy;                  
public int maxZoom = 18;        
public int minZoom = 1;                 
public int zoom = 17;           
private float multiplier;   
public string key = "";         

public string[] maptype;            
public int[] mapSize;                   
public int index;                
public int indexSize;            
public float camDist = 15.0f;       
public int camAngle = 40;           
public int initTime = 3;                    
public int maxWait = 30;        
public bool buttons = true;     
public string dmsLat;                       
public string dmsLon;                           
public float updateRate = 0.1f;     
public bool autoCenter = true;  
public string status;           
public bool gpsFix;                  
public Vector3 iniRef;                   
public bool info;           
public bool triDView = false;   
public bool ready;              
public bool freeCam = false;        
public bool pinchToZoom = true;             
public bool dragToPan = true;           
public bool mapDisabled;                
public bool mapping = false;    
public Transform cam;   
public float userLon;   
public float userLat;

private float levelHeight;
private float smooth = 1.3f;                                
private float yVelocity = 0.0f;  
private float speed;
private Camera mycam;
private float currentOrtoSize;
private LocationInfo loc;
private Vector3 currentPosition;
private Vector3 newUserPos; 
private Vector3 currentUserPos;
private float download;
private WWW www;
private string url = ""; 
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private Rect rect;
private float screenX;
private float screenY;
private Renderer maprender;
private Transform mymap;
private float initPointerSize;
private double tempLat;
private double tempLon;
private bool touchZoom;
private string centre;
private bool centering;
private Texture centerIcon;
private Texture topIcon;
private Texture bottomIcon;
private Texture leftIcon;
private Texture rightIcon;
private GUIStyle arrowIcon;
private float dot;
private bool centered = true;
private int borderTile = 0;
private bool tileLeft;
private bool tileRight;
private bool tileTop;
private bool tileBottom;
private Rect topCursorPos;
private Rect rightCursorPos;
private Rect bottomCursorPos;
private Rect leftCursorPos;


void Awake(){
    //Set the map's tag to GameController
    transform.tag = "GameController";

    cam = Camera.main.transform;
    mycam = Camera.main;
    user = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    //Store most used components and values into variables for faster access.
    mymap = transform;
    maprender = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    screenX = Screen.width;
    screenY = Screen.height;    

    //Add possible values to maptype and mapsize arrays (GOOGLE)
    maptype = new string[]{"satellite","roadmap","hybrid","terrain"};
    mapSize = new int[]{640}; //in pixels

    //Set GUI "center" button label
    if(triDView){
        centre = "refresh";
    }
    //Enable autocenter on 2D-view (default)
    else{
        autoCenter = true;
    }

    //Load required interface textures
    centerIcon = Resources.Load("centerIcon") as Texture2D;
    topIcon = Resources.Load("cursorTop") as Texture2D;
    bottomIcon = Resources.Load("cursorBottom") as Texture2D;
    leftIcon = Resources.Load("cursorLeft") as Texture2D;
    rightIcon = Resources.Load("cursorRight") as Texture2D;

    //Resize GUI according to screen size/orientation 
    if(screenY >= screenX){
        dot = screenY/800.0f;
    }else{
        dot = screenX/800.0f;
    }
}


IEnumerator Start () {

    //Setting variables values on Start
    gpsFix=false;
    rect = new Rect (screenX/10, screenY/10, 8*screenX/10, 8*screenY/10);
    topCursorPos = new Rect(screenX/2-25*dot, 0, 50*dot, 50*dot);
    rightCursorPos = new Rect(screenX-50*dot, screenY/2-25*dot, 50*dot, 50*dot);
    if(!buttons)
        bottomCursorPos = new Rect(screenX/2-25*dot, screenY-50*dot, 50*dot, 50*dot);
    else
        bottomCursorPos = new Rect(screenX/2-25*dot, screenY-50*dot-screenY/12, 50*dot, 50*dot);
    leftCursorPos = new Rect(0, screenY/2-25*dot, 50*dot, 50*dot);
    Vector3 tmp = mymap.eulerAngles;
    tmp.y=180;
    mymap.eulerAngles = tmp;
    initPointerSize = user.localScale.x;
    user.position = new Vector3(0, user.position.y, 0);

    //Initial Camera Settings
    //3D 
    if(triDView){
        mycam.orthographic = false;
        pinchToZoom = false;
        dragToPan = false;
        //Set the camera's field of view according to Screen size so map's visible area is maximized.
        if(screenY > screenX){
            mycam.fieldOfView = 72.5f;
        }else{
            mycam.fieldOfView = 95-(28*(screenX/screenY));
        }
    }
    //2D
    else{
        mycam.orthographic = true;
        mycam.nearClipPlane = 0.1f;
        mycam.farClipPlane = cam.position.y+1;  
        if(screenY >= screenX){
            mycam.orthographicSize = mymap.localScale.z*5.0f;
        }else{
            mycam.orthographicSize = (screenY/screenX)*mymap.localScale.x*5.0f;     
        }
    }

    //The "ready" variable will be true when the map texture has been successfully loaded.
    ready = false; 

    //STARTING LOCATION SERVICES
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    #if (UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR)
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser){

        //This message prints to the Editor Console
        print("Ha sido imposible iniciar los servicios de localizacion.\nComprueba los ajustes de localización de tu teléfono");
        //You can use this "status" variable to show messages in your custom user interface (GUIText, etc.)
        status = "Ha sido imposible iniciar \nlos servicios de localizacion.\nComprueba los ajustes de \nlocalización de tu teléfono";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Application.LoadLevel("0_Login");
    }
    #endif
    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start (3.0f, 3.0f); 
    Input.compass.enabled = true;
    print("Iniciando servicios de localización...");
    status = "Iniciando servicios de localización...";

    // Wait until service initializes
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 30 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1) {
        print("Ha sido imposible iniciar los servicios de localizacion.\nComprueba los ajustes de localización de tu teléfono");
        status = "Ha sido imposible iniciar \nlos servicios de localizacion.\nComprueba los ajustes de \nlocalización de tu teléfono";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Application.LoadLevel("0_Login");
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
        print("Ha sido imposible determinar tu localización\nComprueba los ajustes de localización de tu teléfono");
        status = "Ha sido imposible determinar \ntu localización.\nComprueba los ajustes de \nlocalización de tu teléfono";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Application.LoadLevel("0_Login");
    }

    // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
    else {
        if(!mapDisabled){
            print("GPS conectado. Ajustando posición...");
            status = "GPS conectado!\n Ajustando posición...";
        }
        else{
            print("GPS conectado.");
            status = "GPS conectado!";
        }

        if(!simGPS){
            //Wait in order to find enough satellites and increase GPS accuracy
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(initTime);
            //Set position
            loc  = Input.location.lastData;          
            iniRef.x = ((loc.longitude*20037508.34f/180)/100);
            iniRef.z = (float)(System.Math.Log(System.Math.Tan((90+loc.latitude)*System.Math.PI/360))/(System.Math.PI/180));
            iniRef.z = ((iniRef.z*20037508.34f/180)/100);  
            iniRef.y = 0;
            fixLon = loc.longitude;
            fixLat = loc.latitude; 
            //Successful GPS fix
            gpsFix = true;
            //Update Map for the current location
             StartCoroutine(MapPosition());
        }  
        else{
            //Simulate initialization time
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(initTime);
            //Set Position
            iniRef.x = ((fixLon*20037508.34f/180)/100);
            iniRef.z = (float)(System.Math.Log(System.Math.Tan((90+fixLat)*System.Math.PI/360))/(System.Math.PI/180));
            iniRef.z = (iniRef.z*20037508.34f/180)/100;  
            iniRef.y = 0;
            //Simulated successful GPS fix
            gpsFix = true;
            //Update Map for the current location
            StartCoroutine(MapPosition());
        }    
    }

    //Rescale map, set new camera height, and resize user pointer according to new zoom level
     StartCoroutine(ReScale()); 

    //Set player's position using new location data (every "updateRate" seconds)
    //Default value for updateRate is 0.1. Increase if necessary to improve performance
    InvokeRepeating("MyPosition", 1, updateRate); 

    //Read incoming compass data (every 0.1s)
    InvokeRepeating("Orientate", 1, 0.1f);

    //Get altitude and horizontal accuracy readings using new location data (Default: every 2s)
    InvokeRepeating("AccuracyAltitude", 1, 2);

    //Auto-Center Map on 2D View Mode 
    InvokeRepeating("Check", 1, 0.2f);
}


void MyPosition(){
    if(gpsFix){
        if(!simGPS){
            loc = Input.location.lastData;
            newUserPos.x = ((loc.longitude*20037508.34f/180)/100)-iniRef.x;
            newUserPos.z = (float)(System.Math.Log(System.Math.Tan((90+loc.latitude)*System.Math.PI/360))/(System.Math.PI/180));
            newUserPos.z = ((newUserPos.z*20037508.34f/180)/100)-iniRef.z;   
            dmsLat = convertdmsLat(loc.latitude);
            dmsLon = convertdmsLon(loc.longitude);
            userLon = loc.longitude;
            userLat = loc.latitude;
        }
        else{
            userLon = (18000*(user.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
            userLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(user.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;
            dmsLat = convertdmsLat(userLat);
            dmsLon = convertdmsLon(userLon);
        }
    }   
} 


void Orientate(){
    if(!simGPS && gpsFix){
        heading = Input.compass.trueHeading;
    }
    else{
        heading = user.eulerAngles.y;
    }
}

void AccuracyAltitude(){
    if(gpsFix)
        altitude = loc.altitude;
        accuracy = loc.horizontalAccuracy;
}

void Check(){
    if(autoCenter && triDView == false){
        if(ready == true && mapping == false && gpsFix){
            if (rect.Contains(Vector2.Scale(mycam.WorldToViewportPoint (user.position), new Vector2(screenX, screenY)))){
                //DoNothing
            }
            else{
                centering=true;
                 StartCoroutine(MapPosition());
                 StartCoroutine(ReScale()); 
            }
        }
    }
}

//Auto-Center Map on 3D View Mode when exiting map's collider
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){
    if(other.tag == "Player" && autoCenter && triDView){
         StartCoroutine(MapPosition());
         StartCoroutine(ReScale());
    }
}

//Update Map with the corresponding map images for the current location ============================================
IEnumerator MapPosition(){

    //The mapping variable will only be true while the map is being updated
    mapping = true;

    CursorsOff();

    //CHECK GPS STATUS AND RESTART IF NEEDED

    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Stopped || Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed){
        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start (3.0f, 3.0f);

        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1) {
            print ("Timed out");
            //use the status string variable to print messages to your own user interface (GUIText, etc.)
            status = "Timed out";
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
            print ("Unable to determine device location");
            //use the status string variable to print messages to your own user interface (GUIText, etc.)
            status = "Unable to determine device location";
        }

    }

   //------------------------------------------------------------------ //

    www = null; 
    //Get last available location data
    loc = Input.location.lastData;
    //Make player invisible while updating map
    user.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;


    //Set target latitude and longitude
    if(triDView){
        if(simGPS){
            fixLon = (18000*(user.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
            fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(user.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;   
        }else{
            fixLon = loc.longitude;
            fixLat = loc.latitude;
        }
    }else{
        if(centering){
            if(simGPS){
                fixLon = (18000*(user.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(user.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;   
            }else{
                fixLon = loc.longitude;
                fixLat = loc.latitude;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(borderTile == 0){
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(cam.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;    
                fixLon = (18000*(cam.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
            }
            //North tile
            if (borderTile == 1){
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(cam.position.z+3*mycam.orthographicSize/2+iniRef.z))))-90; 
                fixLon = (18000 *(cam.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
                borderTile=0;   
                tileTop=false;
            }
            //East Tile
            if (borderTile == 2){
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(cam.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;    
                fixLon = (18000*(cam.position.x+3*(screenX*mycam.orthographicSize/screenY)/2+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
                borderTile = 0;
            }
            //South Tile
            if (borderTile == 3){
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(cam.position.z-3*mycam.orthographicSize/2+iniRef.z))))-90; 
                fixLon = (18000*(cam.position.x+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
                borderTile=0;
            }
            //West Tile
            if (borderTile == 4){
                fixLat = ((360/Mathf.PI)*Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f*(cam.position.z+iniRef.z))))-90;    
                fixLon = (18000*(cam.position.x-3*(screenX*mycam.orthographicSize/screenY)/2+iniRef.x))/20037508.34f;
                borderTile=0;
            }
        }
    }


    //MAP ================================================================================
    //Build a valid Google Maps tile request for the current location 

    url= "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+fixLat+","+fixLon+"&zoom="+zoom+"&scale=2&size=640x640&style=feature:all|element:geometry|hue:0x00fff0|lightness:0|gamma:0.21|visibility:on&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape.man_made|element:geometry|color:0x133f42|visibility:on&style=feature:landscape.natural|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|hue:0x00ffd2|saturation:35|lightness:0|gamma:0.5&style=feature:poi|element:geometry.fill|lightness:0|gamma:0.6|visibility:on&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|visibility:on|saturation:0|color:0x2e9470&style=feature:road|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|color:0x05111a&style=feature:road|element:geometry.stroke|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|element:geometry|visibility:off"+"&sensor=false&key="+key;

    tempLat = fixLat;
    tempLon = fixLon;

    //=================================================================================================

    //Proceed with download if a Wireless internet connection is available 
    if(Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork){
        StartCoroutine(Online());
    }   
    //Proceed with download if a 3G/4G internet connection is available 
    else if(Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork){
         StartCoroutine(Online());
    }
    //No internet connection is available. Switching to Offline mode.    
    else{
        Offline();
    }   
}

//ONLINE MAP DOWNLOAD
IEnumerator Online(){
    if(!mapDisabled){
        // Start a download of the given URL
        www = new WWW(url); 
        // Wait for download to complete
        download = (www.progress);
        while(!www.isDone){
            print("Actualizando mapa "+System.Math.Round(download*100)+" %");
            //use the status string variable to print messages to your own user interface (GUIText, etc.)
            status="Actualizando mapa "+System.Math.Round(download*100)+" %";
            yield return null;
        }
        //Show download progress and apply texture
        if(www.error == null){
            print("Actualizando mapa 100 %");
            print("Mapa preparado!");
            //use the status string variable to print messages to your own user interface (GUIText, etc.)
            status = "Actualizando mapa 100 %\nMapa preparado!";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
            maprender.material.mainTexture = null;
            Texture2D tmp;
            tmp = new Texture2D(1280, 1280, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            maprender.material.mainTexture = tmp;
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tmp);  
        }
        //Download Error. Switching to offline mode
        else{
            print("Error en el mapa:"+www.error);
            //use the status string variable to print messages to your own user interface (GUIText, etc.)
            status = "Error en el mapa:"+www.error;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (4);
            maprender.material.mainTexture = null;
            Offline();
        }
        maprender.enabled = true;
    }
    ReSet();
    user.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    ready = true;
    mapping = false;

}

//USING OFFLINE BACKGROUND TEXTURE
void Offline(){
    if(!mapDisabled){
        maprender.material.mainTexture=Resources.Load("offline") as Texture2D;
        maprender.enabled = true;
    }
    ReSet();
    ready = true;
    mapping = false;
    user.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
}

//Re-position map and camera using updated data
void ReSet(){
    Vector3 tmp = transform.position;
    tmp.x = (float)((tempLon*20037508.34f/180)/100)-iniRef.x;
    tmp.z = (float)(System.Math.Log(System.Math.Tan((90+tempLat)*System.Math.PI/360))/(System.Math.PI/180));
    tmp.z = ((tmp.z*20037508.34f/180)/100)-iniRef.z;
    transform.position = tmp;
    if(!freeCam){
        cam.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, cam.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    if(triDView == false && centering){
        centered = true;
        autoCenter = true;
        centering = false;
    }
}



void Update(){

    //Rename GUI "center" button label
    if(!triDView){
        if(cam.position.x != user.position.x || cam.position.z != user.position.z)
            centre ="center";
        else
            centre ="refresh";
    }

    //User pointer speed
    if(realSpeed){
        speed = userSpeed*0.05f;
    }
    else{
        speed = userSpeed*10000/(Mathf.Pow(2, zoom)*1.0f);
    }

    //3D-2D View Camera Toggle (use only while game is stopped) 
    if(triDView && !freeCam){
        cam.parent = user;
        if(ready)
            cam.LookAt(user);
    }   

    if(ready){  
        if(!simGPS){
            //Smoothly move pointer to updated position
            currentUserPos.x = user.position.x;
            currentUserPos.x = Mathf.Lerp (user.position.x, newUserPos.x, 2.0f*Time.deltaTime);
            currentUserPos.z = user.position.z;
            currentUserPos.z = Mathf.Lerp (user.position.z, newUserPos.z, 2.0f*Time.deltaTime);
            user.position = new Vector3(currentUserPos.x, user.position.y, currentUserPos.z);

            //Update rotation
            if(System.Math.Abs(user.eulerAngles.y-heading) >= 5){
                float newAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(user.eulerAngles.y, heading, ref yVelocity, smooth);
                user.eulerAngles = new Vector3(user.eulerAngles.x, newAngle, user.eulerAngles.z);
            }
        }
        else{
            //When GPS Emulator is enabled, user position is controlled by keyboard input.
            if(mapping == false){
                //Use keyboard input to move the player
                if (Input.GetKey ("up") || Input.GetKey ("w")){
                    user.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
                }
                if (Input.GetKey ("down") || Input.GetKey ("s")){
                    user.transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
                }
                //rotate pointer when pressing Left and Right arrow keys
                user.Rotate(Vector3.up, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*80*Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }   
    }

    if(mapping && !mapDisabled){
        //get download progress while images are still downloading
        if(www != null)
            download = www.progress;
    }   

    //Enable/Disable map renderer 
    if(mapDisabled)
        maprender.enabled = false;
    else
        maprender.enabled = true;


void CheckBorders(){
    //Reached left tile border
    if(Mathf.Round((mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x)*100.0f)/100.0f <= Mathf.Round((mymap.position.x-mymap.localScale.x*5)*100.0f)/100.0f){
        //show button for borderTile=4;
        tileLeft = true;
    }else{
        //hide button
        tileLeft = false;
    }
    //Reached right tile border
    if(Mathf.Round((mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mycam.pixelWidth, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x)*100.0f)/100.0f >= Mathf.Round((mymap.position.x+mymap.localScale.x*5)*100.0f)/100.0f){
        //show button for borderTile=2;
        tileRight = true;
    }else{
        //hide button
        tileRight = false;
    }
    //Reached bottom tile border
    if(Mathf.Round((mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0, cam.position.y)).z)*100.0f)/100.0f <= Mathf.Round((mymap.position.z-mymap.localScale.z*5)*100.0f)/100.0f){
        //show button for borderTile=3;
        tileBottom = true;
    }else{
        //hide button
        tileBottom = false;
    }
    //Reached top tile border
    if(Mathf.Round((mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, mycam.pixelHeight, cam.position.y)).z)*100.0f)/100.0f >= Mathf.Round((mymap.position.z+mymap.localScale.z*5)*100.0f)/100.0f){
        //show button for borderTile=1;
        tileTop = true;
    }else{
        //hide button
        tileTop = false;
    }
}

//Disable surrounding tiles cursors
void CursorsOff(){
    tileTop = false;
    tileBottom = false;
    tileLeft = false;
    tileRight = false;
}

//Clamp the camera position
void ClampCam(){
    Vector3 tmp = cam.position;
    tmp.x = Mathf.Clamp(cam.position.x, 
                        mymap.position.x-(mymap.localScale.x*5)+(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mycam.pixelWidth, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x-mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x)/2, 
                        mymap.position.x+(mymap.localScale.x*5)-(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mycam.pixelWidth, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x-mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0.5f, cam.position.y)).x)/2 );
    tmp.z = Mathf.Clamp(cam.position.z, 
                        mymap.position.z-(mymap.localScale.z*5)+(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, mycam.pixelHeight, cam.position.y)).z-mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0, cam.position.y)).z)/2, 
                        mymap.position.z+(mymap.localScale.z*5)-(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, mycam.pixelHeight, cam.position.y)).z-mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0, cam.position.y)).z)/2 );                
    cam.position = tmp;
}

}
```

Those are the screenshots.
[Editor and Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFAz3.png)

[iOS device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0bP2.png)

Comment: Something is likely failing on iOS. Why not post the complete code that generates the url then the complete error code

Comment: In Xcode appears: "You are using download over http. Currently unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https." And next: "Map error:unsupported URL"

Comment: If I put this url it works in iOS device, but the map don't have the style I want. (url= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+fixLat+","+fixLon+"&zoom="+zoom+"&scale=2&size=640x640&format=jpg&maptype="+maptype[index]+"&sensor=false&key="+key; )

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What does it look like in the Editor and iOS?It would make sense to upload screenshot of both. Without them, I  can't tell what your problem is. While at this, you may want to add what Unity version you are using and what class you are using to access the url. Again, without putting the code you use to access the url how can somebody help you? This would just be a guessing game.

Comment: Sorry. I've put the code above. Thanks.

Comment: 1.Take a screenshot of what it looks like in the Editor. 2.Take a screenshot of what it looks like in iOS. Upload both `Images`. 3. Tell us the what Unity version you are using...5.3xxx....Thanks for uploading code. I will check if this question is updated in hours.

Comment: The problem is that the map appears in the unity editor, and in Android devices, but not in iOS devices. I upload the screenshots in a moment

Comment: That's what  I thought but then you said "**If I put this url it works in iOS device, but the map don't have the style I want**". So this means it is working but not as you want it......Is it working on iOS or not? Please tell us what Unity version you are running. When I get back, I will try to replicate this problem with the code you provided.

Comment: I've put the screenshots above. Unity version is 5.3.5f1. It's working in iOS if I put the short url. But when I put the longer one only works in editor and android device

Comment: Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I haven't had time to switch my os to mac to test this. I will do that today. If you want to start the troubleshooting before me, you try to replace the WWW API with [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html ) code. This might fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran the code in your question and was able to replicate your problem. This is happening due to new restriction on using http connections instead of https on iOS. Just like I mentioned in my comment, replacing `WWW` with `UnityWebRequest` solved this problem.

Also, you are unnecessarily creating new textures each time with  `new Texture2D(1280, 1280, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);` is executed. This should be done with Unity's UI Component `RawImage`. In this case, no unnecessary memory allocation.

All you have to do to the code in your question is to remove the `WWW` API and use `UnityWebRequest`. Also remove `Renderer` or `Texture2D` and use `RawImage` to display your map. Below is a simple test script I used to test this. It runs on the both `Editor`,`iOS` and possibly all other platforms.

```
public class Gpsconnect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage imageDisp;
    public float fixLat = 42.3627f;
    public float fixLon = -71.05686f;
    public int zoom = 4;
    public string key = "";
    public Vector3 iniRef;
    public Transform cam;
    private Camera mycam;
    private string url = "";

    //Update Map with the corresponding map images for the current location ============================================
    IEnumerator load()
    {
        yield return null;
        mycam = Camera.main;
        fixLat = ((360 / Mathf.PI) * Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(0.00001567855943f * (cam.position.z - 3 * mycam.orthographicSize / 2 + iniRef.z)))) - 90;
        fixLon = (18000 * (cam.position.x + iniRef.x)) / 20037508.34f;

        //MAP ================================================================================
        //Build a valid Google Maps tile request for the current location 

        url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + fixLat + "," + fixLon + "&zoom=" + zoom + "&scale=2&size=640x640&style=feature:all|element:geometry|hue:0x00fff0|lightness:0|gamma:0.21|visibility:on&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape.man_made|element:geometry|color:0x133f42|visibility:on&style=feature:landscape.natural|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|hue:0x00ffd2|saturation:35|lightness:0|gamma:0.5&style=feature:poi|element:geometry.fill|lightness:0|gamma:0.6|visibility:on&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|visibility:on|saturation:0|color:0x2e9470&style=feature:road|element:geometry.fill|visibility:on|color:0x05111a&style=feature:road|element:geometry.stroke|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|element:geometry|visibility:off" + "&sensor=false&key=" + key;

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture(url);
        yield return www.Send();
        Debug.Log("Done: ");

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error while downloading image: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            imageDisp.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(load());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your work!! Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!